# How Can I re- write this using Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Just a quick question .. How canI re-write this using Linq

```
var turbo =
            (from t in _cat.Data
                where t.Veh_ID == id && t.Engine == engine
                select t.PartNum).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tried  something like this but stuck!

```
var t = _cat.Data.where (x =>x.Veh_ID == id && x.Engine == engine).Select() // << stuck here
```

Please help Thank you

Comment: For the record what you have there is already linq. What you seem to be asking is how to do it using method syntax. In terms of compiled code the syntax you are using is actually converted to method syntax by the compiler before compilation so it shouldn't matter which you use.

Comment: Given that you *already* use LINQ, why do you want to change the syntax? Is there another problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: alright i see.. i think i confused myself .. Thank you for that info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var turbo = _cat.Data
                .Where (t => t.Veh_ID == id && t.Engine == engine)
                .Select(t => t.PartNum)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var turbo = _cat.Data
    .Where(x => x.Veh_ID == id && t.Engine == engine)
    .Select(x => x.PartNum)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
var turbo = _cat.Data.Where(t.Veh_ID == id && t.Engine == engine)
                     .Select(x => x.PartNumber)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```